Punishment for hiring false witnesses
We read in Bava Kamma 55b:

It is taught that Rabbi Yehoshua said: [One] is exempt from liability according to human laws but liable according to the laws of Heaven [if he] hires false witnesses to testify.

Halacha says that if you testify falsely and are caught, you get the same penalty as the defendant would have gotten, and by human hands.  But does this baraita add that if you just hire someone to testify falsely, you can't be punished by human hands?  Are there commentaries that elaborate on this?

It’s like אין שליח לדבר עבירה

Yes, the Baraita does teach this.
The Maharam mentions in his responsa (300 in the Prague edition) that the reason why the one who hired the false witnesses is exempt is because he has only caused a grama, an indirect action:

כל אלו דיני [דגרמא] הם בנזקין ופטור
All these cases of damage are ones of indirect action and are exempt

The Sefer HaTashbetz (II 114) concurs, and clarifies that the reason why the person is chayav bidei shamayim is because damage did come about through his hands, despite it not being direct.

Interestingly:
The Rosh notes a case brought by the son of Rabbi Yechiel, where people deliberately hired false witnesses:

A woman hired false witnesses preemptively against someone else, who had stated he would produce witnesses against her (which she knew must be false because she knew he was lying about his claim - it was regarding his claim that he had betrothed her).
In that case, the false witnesses did not end up testifying, but it did become known that they planned on doing so, and the Rosh states that in this case the she wasn't even punished bidei shamayim, but was placed under a 30 day excommunication as a warning to others.

