Punishment for false testimony favoring the accused
One of the Ten Commandments is: "Don't give false testimony".  This is generally understood as falsely testifying the accused is guilty, when he is innocent.  One penalty is that the false witness, if caught, is given the same penalty the accused would have gotten had he been found guilty.
But what if the false witness says the accused is innocent, when he knows he is guilty?  If the false witness is caught, what penalty is applied to him?
We read in Bava Kamma 55b:

It is taught that Rabbi Yehoshua said: [One] is exempt from liability according to human laws but liable according to the laws of Heaven [if he] hires false witnesses to testify.

But here the witness is not hired.  He spontaneously decided to help the accused.  (You can think of many possible reasons.)

related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/144166/759


One of the Ten Commandments is: "Don't give false testimony".

That would be true whether someone is falsely testifying  someone is guilty or innocent. The issue is false testimony.

The penalty is that the false witness, if caught, is given the same penalty the accused would have gotten had he been found guilty.

Not always. This is limited to  the case of Eidim Zommim where two witnesses testify that original witnesses were not at the scene of the crime because they were with us elsewhere.  Usually they are  given the punishment they wanted the person who they falsely testifying to receive. In a case where that is not possible for technical reasons they would receive malkos (lashes). The situation mentioned in the OP is also one where the one giving false testimony is given lashes. The Rambam Hilchos Edus 20:9   כָּךְ קִבְּלוּ חֲכָמִים שֶׁשְּׁנַיִם שֶׁהִרְשִׁיעוּ אֶת הַצַּדִּיק וְהִצְדִּיקוּ אֶת הָרָשָׁע בְּעֵדוּתָן. וּבָאוּ עֵדִים אֲחֵרִים וֶהֱזִימוּם וְהִצְדִּיקוּ אֶת הַצַּדִּיק וְהִרְשִׁיעוּ אֶת הָרָשָׁע. הֲרֵי עֵדִים הָרִאשׁוֹנִים לוֹקִים אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁלֹּא הִרְשִׁיעוּ הַצַּדִּיק לְהַלְקוֹתוֹ. our Sages received the following tradition: When two people cause an innocent person to be condemned or a guilty person to be vindicated through their testimony and two others come and disqualify their testimony through hazamah vindicating the innocent person and condemning the guilty, the first pair of witnesses receive lashes

It is taught that Rabbi Yehoshua said: [One] is exempt from liability according to human laws but liable according to the laws of Heaven [if he] hires false witnesses to testify.

This is a slightly different concept. As Rashi on that Gemora explains, Geroma b'nizekin potur. (very roughly) meaning that  as long as someone can claim in Beis Din that "I did not do that " even though he will be punished in the next world for his involvement, human courts (beis din) usually will not punish him for it.   Reason being that you can always blame other people for causing things to happen, the people who took the money to testify falsely  weren't being forced to do so, we don't want an American legal system where lawyers just go after whoever has the deeper pockets claiming they were the ones who caused it and the ones at fault etc.etc.etc. But that is just another case in the general  concept of Geroma B'Nizokin. It isn't unique to witnesses.

I don't understand.  Is "None" the answer to my question: "What penalty is applied to him?" ?

No. Lashes is the punishment applied to him.

Do you have the reference?  Thanks.

It is the Rambam I mentioned in the post. Reread it.

I did, but thought the second set of witnesses simply nullified the first.  Actually, they don't, if they claim they were with the first set somewhere far from the crime scene.

I'm not sure what you perceive the Rambam as saying but  he is saying that whether witnesses testified falsely for or against someone (innocent or guilty) and they were proven to be testifying falsely through the process of hazama the original witnesses would receive lashes.

"In a case where that is not possible for technical reasons they would receive malkos" - this is right in a case where the witnesses testify against someone; but in this case, they aren't testifying against anyone, because their testimony can't impact the other set of witnesses because they're not claiming עמנו הייתם. It seems to me that the Rambam you're quoting is just giving the source for the previous halacha (20:8) which is limited to four cases. When he says שהרשיעו את הצדיק והצדיקו את הרשע he means both at the same time (as in a monetary dispute), not הצדיקו את הרשע by itself.

I just realized my suggested interpretation of the words והצדיקו את הרשע ("as in a monetary dispute") is completely wrong, because that isn't one of those four cases. It could refer to the witnesses themselves (they made themselves out to be telling the truth) but that sounds a little strange. Those words actually don't appear in the Gemara (Makkot 2b) so I wonder what the Rambam meant by adding them. If he meant what you said that would explain it, but I don't see on what basis it can be read that way.

@Schmerel -- I am still not convinced the unmasked false witness who testified in favor of the accused gets lashes.  First, what is the Rambam's source?  Second, his words: "When two people cause an innocent person to be condemned and [not or]  a guilty person to be vindicated" may refer to two people, not two cases: the accused (who is innocent) and someone else (who is guilty) in the same case.
